# There is a problem with Oracle ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, cx-oracle, oracle18c

I need to substitute the following values into select query. but i got the error as i mentioned below

```
def addSoil(self):
    name = self.ent_name.get()
    texture = self.ent_texture.get()
    colour = self.ent_colour.get()
    capacity = self.ent_capacity.get()
    equation = self.ent_equation.get()

    try:
        con = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hr@192.168.56.1/xepdb1')
        cursor = con.cursor()

        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO soildata (soil_name, soil_text, soil_colour, soil_waterhold, soil_chemicalequ) '
                       'VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', (name,texture,colour,capacity,equation))

        con.commit()

    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        print("There is a problem with Oracle", e)

    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if con:
            con.close()
```

Comment: what are the types stored into your `self.ent_*.` ? Check the names of `soil_name, soil_text, soil_colour, soil_waterhold, soil_chemicalequ`

Comment: Try changing the five placeholders `%s` to something like `:1,:2,:3,:4,:5`.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong placeholder syntax. You need to do something like this:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO soildata (soil_name, soil_text, soil_colour, soil_waterhold, soil_chemicalequ) '
               'VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)', (name,texture,colour,capacity,equation))
```

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-by-name-or-position) as well for further help.